# Chorographer issue in Android Service

Tags: java, android, gps, android-notifications

I have a class which makes GPS requests at an interval of 1 second.
I also have a `Service` which keeps a notification alive.
This service updates the text of the notification with data from the GPS, at an interval of 1 second.
In the application, I have a `BroadcastRecevier` which listens to the service updates and changes some text within the application.

I get the Choreographer issue (`Choreographer(691): Skipped xxx frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.`)

I've added my code below, but deleted the unnecessary code from it.
The debugging challenge is that usually it takes 30-90 minutes for the error to occur and not even every time.

Any suggestion?

```
import /*....*/;


public class SomeClass extends Service {
    private static Context context;
    private static Timer timer;
    private static Handler handler = new Handler();
    /* Notification begin */
    private static Notification.Builder builder;
    private static RemoteViews ongl;
    private static Notification notification;
    private static NotificationManager notificationManager;
    private static int notifyID;
    /* Notification end */
    /* GPScalculator begin */
    private static GpsCalculator gpsCalculator;
    private static Boolean goalAchieved = false;
    /* Sound notification */
    private static MediaPlayer pl;
    private static int kmCount;
    /* Timer start*/
    private static TimerTask timerTask;
    /* Timer end*/

    public static final String NOTIFICATION = "...";
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        context = this;
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent nintent = new Intent(this,MyClass.class);
        nintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        notifyID = 1;
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, nintent, 0);
        builder = new Notification.Builder(context);

        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        builder.setTicker("Run started");
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        builder.setAutoCancel(false);
        builder.setPriority(2);
        builder.setOngoing(true);
        ongl = new RemoteViews(NOTIFICATION, R.layout.ongoing_notification);
        builder.setContent(ongl);
        notification = builder.build();
        startForeground(notifyID,notification);

        pl = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.applause6);
        pl.start();
        kmCount = 0;

        gpsCalculator = new GpsCalculator(distanceToRun, runId);
        Map<String, Object> mp = (Map<String, Object>) intent.getSerializableExtra("upr");
        gpsCalculator.run(mp,this);

        startRun();
        return(START_NOT_STICKY);
    }
    public void startRun(){
        timer = new Timer();


        timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {

                //use a handler to run a toast that shows the current timestamp
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        Date dateNow = new Date();
                        String timeNow = String.valueOf(dateNow.getTime()/1000);
                        int timeLapsed = Integer.parseInt(timeNow) - Integer.parseInt(runId);

                        int hours = timeLapsed / 3600;
                        int minutes = (timeLapsed/60) % 60;
                        int seconds = timeLapsed % 60;

                        String hrs = String.valueOf(hours);
                        String mns = String.valueOf(minutes);
                        String scs = String.valueOf(seconds);


                        currentDistance = gpsCalculator.getTotalDistance();
                        /* Notify split */
                        int currentKm = currentDistance/1000;
                        if(currentKm > kmCount){
                            kmCount = currentKm;
                            pl.start();
                        }

                        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                        map.put("hrs",hrs);
                        map.put("mns",mns);
                        map.put("scs",scs);
                        map.put("distance",String.valueOf(currentDistance));
                        Intent intent1 = new Intent(NOTIFICATION);
                        if(distanceToRun<currentDistance){
                            if(!goalAchieved){
                                pl = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.cheer2);
                                pl.start();
                                new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(
                                    new Runnable() {
                                        public void run() {
                                            pl = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.applause6);
                                        }
                                    },
                                    4000);
                                goalAchieved = true;
                                ongl.setTextColor(R.id.ong_dist_txt, Color.parseColor("#FF1414"));
                                intent1.putExtra("finishedRun", true);
                                runResults = gpsCalculator.getRunResults();
                            }
                        }
                        intent1.putExtra("runProgress", (java.io.Serializable) map);
                        sendBroadcast(intent1);
                        ongl.setTextViewText(R.id.ong_time_txt,hrs+":"+mns+":"+scs);
                        notificationManager.notify(notifyID, notification);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 1000);
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return(null);
    }

    public static void stopRun() {
        if (timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
            timer = null;
        }
        if(gpsCalculator != null){
            gpsCalculator.stop();
        }
    }

    public static Map<String, Object> getRunResults() {
        return runResults;
    }

    public static String getRunId(){
        return runId;
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of data are you (de)serializing from/into the intent? I'm specifically referring to `intent.getSerializableExtra("upr")` - (un)marshalling `Serializable` implementations is known to be fairly inefficient and slow on Android and the performance hit will definitely be noticeable if the `Map` contains a large number of items and/or complex/nested objects. You mention it generally takes a while for the issue to kick in. I'm going to venture a guess a say that this map grows over time?

Comment: `intent.getSerializableExtra("upr")` is accessing user profile data, user name user id and so on. This is an Object which has 12 pairs. One of them is an URL. 
The map from `intent1.putExtra("runProgress", (java.io.Serializable) map);` doesn't grow.

Comment: I've just created a new `Thread' for the `Runnable', although I don't know what this should do, but was mentioned on other threads on SO